# According to tsconfig.json documentation, referenced projects must use the composite setting. This doesn't seem to be true. What is the effect?

Tags: typescript

The [official typescript documentation about project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) says:

> Referenced projects must have the new composite setting enabled.

I'm using typescript 5.1.6 and this doesn't seem to be the case. As far as I can tell, `tsc --build` builds what follows without issue. So my question is, what is the effect of using project references without using composite?

---

#### Project Structure

```
.
├── package.json
├── src1/
│   ├── foo.spec.ts
│   └── foo.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.spec.json
└── tsconfig.src.json
```

#### ./package.json

```
{
  "name": "declaration-file-in-proj-ref",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc --build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

#### ./src1/foo.spec.ts

```
export const X = 10;
```

#### ./src1/foo.ts

```
export const X = 10;
```

#### ./tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2018",
        "module": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "es2020",
            "dom",
            "DOM.Iterable"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "tscbuild",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noErrorTruncation": true,
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.src.json"
        },
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
        },
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "." // prevent this config from including all files
    ]
}
```

#### ./tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src1/**/*.spec.ts",
    "./src1/**/*.helpers.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

#### ./tsconfig.src.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "./src1/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./src1/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
}
```